# Where can I find download history of Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer

Is there any way to get Downloads history of IE?

We get Downloads history of Firefox from `downloads.sqlite` file and we get download history of Chrome from history.sqlite file.

But how to find out in IE?

Did some tryout with `FindFirstUrlCacheEntry()` but output is not as expected. Read about `index.dat` file, but it is not updated as I browse in IE.

Comment: What does this have to do with C++?

Comment: [Windows 7: Internet Explorer - View and Track Downloads](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/154956-internet-explorer-view-track-downloads.html)